# Creating indexes on Interval Range partition in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a huge data to process every month. Before this I used to create range partition followed by indexes on that partition. I want to eliminate the task of creating partition every month by using range interval partition, but how can I eliminate creating indexes every time for these monthly partitions.

I am using Oracle database.

Comment: what do you mean by 'followed by creating indexes on that partition'? In Oracle, you create the table and the index, and if the index is local, a new partition is added automatically when you add a partition to the table. Same happens with interval partitioning.

Comment: Okay so just to clarify, if new interval partition and its sub partition is created and if local index is created on the table, will that partition be indexed automatically?

Comment: yes, all local indexes will get new partitions

Comment: After creating the table with interval partition, And when I ran some job to insert data, it shows the following           
ORA-14251 : Specified subpartition doesnot exist.    

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Either edit your question to show your CREATE TABLE and INSERT, or ask a new question about the problem. This is NOT an index problem, it is probable a problem with your DDL and/or DML